# How do I get ContentItems from ContentType using DNN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'd like to select all contentItems of Fruits contentType and store them into an array for easy access.

```
public array GetFruitNutrition(int itemId) 
{
    array fruitsArray = DotNetNuke.Entities.Content.Data.DataService.GetContentItemsByContentType(Fruits);
    return fruitsArray[itemId].Nutrition;
}
```

Are there any ways to make this possible? I'm fine with alternatives too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DotNetNuke.Entities.Content.ContentController.GetContentItemsByContentType`](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/dnn-api/?topic=html/040ab20b-1d33-b4b9-d181-2b6a5e0b07fc.htm) instead of going directly to the data service.

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentTypeController().GetContentTypes().SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.ContentType == "MyCompany_Fruit");
ContentItem[] fruit = new ContentController().GetContentItemsByContentType(contentType.ContentTypeId).ToArray();
```

Comment: While we're at it, what's the best way for me to get contentTypeId?   
I'm attempting to make a List Visualizer with a Sorting and Filtering option, would it be wise to use arrays? Or are there easier ways?

Comment: I've added code to retrieve a content type, but a fuller example is at https://github.com/EngageSoftware/Engage-Jackrabbit/blob/3d170d25ae327666eb698523edf80b27d21eab12/Jackrabbit/Components/ContentItemRepository.cs#L230-L240

Comment: Is this do-able with an evoq content license? I seem to be running into various errors such as "Sequence contains no matching element"

Comment: @ChunYin, yes, this should be the same whether it's licensed or not.  You will need to create the content type before you can query for it (take a look at that example in the comment above, where it creates it if it doesn't exist, and then uses it for querying)

Comment: I mean if I need the API key here: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/administrators/structured-content/create-api-key.html

Comment: @ChunYin, my understanding is that the Liquid Content™ (Structured Content) component is _not_ connected to these platform APIs but is totally separate.  If you're trying to access content in Evoq microservices (e.g. Liquid Content™), take a look at https://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/microservices/creating-apps-that-use-microservices.html